# Why isn't there guava Objects.equal(Object, Object) to primitive types?

Tags: java, performance, guava

Why isn't there an [`Objects.equal`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#equal%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) receiving as an argument each primitive type?

I know you can box the value via `#valueOf` or let each primitive be autoboxed, but don't you lose performance doing that? That's something that I've been wondering about for sometime.

Imagine I have something like

```
public class Foo {
    private final int integerValue;
    private final boolean booleanValue;
    private final Bar bar;

    public Foo(int integerValue, boolean booleanValue, Bar bar) {
        this.integerValue = integerValue;
        this.booleanValue = booleanValue;
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("boxing")
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof Foo) {
            Foo that = (Foo) object;

            return Objects.equal(this.integerValue, that.integerValue)
                     && Objects.equal(this.booleanValue, that.booleanValue)
                     && Objects.equal(this.bar, that.bar);
        }
        return false;
    }

    // hashCode implementation using guava also.
}
```

Is this the best way to implement `equals`? The primitive values are going to be autoboxed, suffering (even if it's a little) a performance degradation. I could just use `==` for them, but for me it would break the "flow" of reading the equals method, turning it a little ugly. So I wonder why guava lib don't have an `Objects.equal` for each primitive type. Does someone know the answer?

**EDIT**

There's for the [MoreObjects.toStringHelper](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.ToStringHelper.html) overload for each primitive (but byte), that's one the reason I wondered about not having for `Objects#equal`. Also, using [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) argument, it would turn the `equals` method safer because you can change `int` for `Integer` without having to worry about equal correctness.

[Guava docs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#equal%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: About your edit - it seems like `ToStringHelper` is a member of `Objects` because all `Object` instances have `toString()` in common. The fact that the helper itself takes `int` arguments, etc. is only because an `Object` might contain an `int` (to be included in `toString()` result). Hope that makes sense.

Comment: but if it's because you might have an `int` field, then the same applies for `Objects#equal`. Although different from `Objects#equal`, that can be substituted by `==`, there's nothing you can use in `StringHelper#add` to avoid autoboxing. Thus, the primitive methods. Or at least that's what I think :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I could just use `==` for them, but for me it would break the "flow" of reading the equals method, turning it a little ugly.

This is not a convincing enough reason to add an overload of that method for each primitive type to the Guava API - every method that an API exposes has to be documented, tested, and maintained. It doesn't make sense when the only advantage is aesthetics.

Comment: I see the point, but we often do stuff to let the code become more readable. Not that this is the case, but I don't know how hard would it be to maintain this overloaded methods (not a critic, I really don't know besides test and documentation).

Comment: The cost includes additional clutter in the Javadoc of the `Objects` class for every user who goes through there trying to find something, as well, for a fairly limited (and debatable) benefit.  Additionally, I'd have to admit I would find it _really odd_ for there to be special `equals` handling for primitive types in a class named `Objects`.

Comment: I also find the code would be easier to read, more efficient (avoid boxing), and safer (in case you would change a field from int to Integer for example, and using `==` would break the implementation). Another advantage is that it would be easier to add a generation template in the IDE.

Comment: @LouisWasserman that's a good argument. It's odd having this kind of method in a class named `Objects`. But there's the benefit of performance and safer method. Anyway, I think I got my response :)

Answer (score 2):

> I know you can box the value via #valueOf or let each primitive be autoboxed, but don't you lose performance doing that?

True, but for performance-sensitive code, you would definitely want to use `==` anyway to get a simple `if_icmpeq` opcode rather than invoking a method. So if you're using `Objects.equal` at all, you're probably not writing performance-sensitive code, and probably won't notice the cost of autoboxing.

I'm not saying that a primitive version of `Objects.equal` would have zero benefit, but it's probably not worth adding several methods to the library.